# check if exists in two coma separated values mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am having an issue where I have a table in a database which stores values in this form `1,3,4,55,6,22,44` and I have an array which is dynamic from the client side it can be like `2,55,33,1,33,99`

I want to make a query to select this field if the at least any value matches between the fields.

Like select the field if in the database value there exists `24` and I have `23,24,55,66` from the user array

I think this can be done with `find_in_set()` or the `IN` keyword

Comment: Another good example of why you shouldn't store separate values in a single column. I would recommend ditching what you're doing and making a relational table instead of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a good practice to create comma seperated values in a column. Usually people feel that it was the easiest and simplest method,  but it is not. Searching and modification will be so hard. Find set can be used if you have a single item to search ; In your case you can do it like this. Implode the array with `|` and use it in regular expression.

```
<?php 
    $arr = Array(2,55,33,1,33,99);
    echo 'select * from table where CONCAT(",", `field`, ",") REGEXP ",('.implode("|",$arr).'),"';
?>
```

Comment: This is a good idea, but I'm not sure the regular expression is right.   The expression should look like `',1,|,2,|,3,'`.

Comment: i can not understand how to really use this ??/

Comment: @sonamSharma you said you have an array that is what i have created `Array(2,55,33,1,33,99);` instead of that you have to use your own array. the second line generates a query in that  change `table` with  your table name and `field` with your field name. Execute that query.

Comment: and don't even do this with your data to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

For comparing two arrays, you should use:

```
array_intersect()
```

after converting table data into array as well.

[Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php)